# after navbar is position = fixed everything written after is over flowing

Tags: html, css

```
.navbar {
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: fixed;
    /* width: 34%; */
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

nav li {
    float: left;
    color: white;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px 11px;
    margin: 0px 39px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
}


<p>We are an Official and Authentic Curren watches store. Our premium watches are designed beautifully and reasonably priced that fits in everyone's budget. Buy your favorite Curren Brand from our online shop. Quality Watches for Less!</p>
```

---

now the problem is that when the navbar is fixed and try to add a heading or a paragraph is goes beside the navbar.PLease help me i am a beginner

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use css *z-index* property into .navbar class. I have made below changes in navbar class, try this
.navbar {
**z-index: 10;**
border: 2px solid red;
position: fixed;
/* width: 34%; */
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
}

Comment: Thanks i will try it